# How to extend spring security oauth2 default AuthorizationEndpoint to write my own custom logic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Oauth2 implicit grant type and I have to write my custom logic when user is authorized for which I want to extend AuthorizationEndpoint.java. I have tried to search on google/stackeoverflow but did not found exact answer for it.
I am using spring-security-oauth2-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar .
Can any one help me on this?

I have also tried to do below as I saw this on stackoverflow:
Writing my own Actionmapping CustomEndpoint.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/external/oauth/authorize"}, method={RequestMethod.POST}, params={"user_oauth_approval"})
    public View approveOrDeny(@RequestParam Map<String, String> approvalParameters, Map<String, ?> model, SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {
        //Existing code
        //Custom logic
    }


    @RequestMapping(value={"/external/oauth/authorize"})
    public ModelAndView authorize(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters, SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {
        //Existing code
        //Custom logic
    }
```

And configuring pathmapping as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {      

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/external/oauth/token");
    }

}
```

But it is not working.
Can any one please how to solve this?